# JAVASCRIPT: Class method returns a promise. But I want it to return the resolved result. How do I rewrite the class method?

Tags: javascript, ajax, class

This is my class.

```
export MyClass {
    
    private readonly ServiceEndpoint: string = 
    "/xxx/xxx.DMS.UI.Root/Services/ConfigurationAPI.svc/";
    
    
    public async GetAllCompanies(): Promise<CompanyDto[]> {
    return fetchAsync(
        `${this.ServiceEndpoint}Company`,
        'GET'
        )
      .then(value => value.GetAllCompaniesResult);
  }

}
```

Presently, this method returns a Promise <CompanyDto[]>. How do I rewrite it so that it returns only the result CompanyDto[]?

Comment: You cannot. Fetching something over the network takes some time and is asynchronous, you get the results only later, it is impossible to immediately return them.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing `await` keyword here. Can you please try using `await`?

```
export MyClass {

  private readonly ServiceEndpoint: string = 
    "/xxx/xxx.DMS.UI.Root/Services/ConfigurationAPI.svc/";

  public async GetAllCompanies(): Promise<CompanyDto[]> {
    let result = await fetchAsync(
      `${this.ServiceEndpoint}Company`,
      'GET'
    )
    .then(value => value.GetAllCompaniesResult);

    return result; 
  }
}
```

Comment: That still returns a promise.